# Django 2.1 - creating the correct path URL for primary keys

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am new to Django and I am trying to create a school database webapp as a training exercise.(using Django 2.1)

I set up two models School and Student. I have the home page being a list view of all the schools in the database. Each of these schools is an anchor reference to display the school details and a list of all the schools students. Each school student is also an anchor reference to the Student detail page.

The error am getting is on my path on my urls page.

```
path('<int:pk>/<int:cpk>/',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_details'),
```

This line gets the url to output the primary key of the school that I am currently on and the primary key on the student I selected.

When I click the student name it goes to the student with the same primary key as the school since the url is (basic_app/1/1/). How do I get it to pull from the second number in the url (ckp) and display that primary key data?

For example, school with the pk of 1 has 10 students. On the school detail page it list all the students. When I click on student 3, the url will look like basic_app/1/3/ (based upon the above path code above) but it will only show the detail for student 1. What do I have to edit in order to get this to go the the right student (views.py, models.py, urls.py, html file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it right, your problem is basically that when you visit `basic_app/1/3/` you want to see the details for the student whose primary key is 3, but instead you see a student with primary key 1.

If that's the case, it's because in your view you're using the URL field `pk` while instead you should be using `cpk`. Try changing your URL pattern to look like this:

```
path('<int:school_pk>/<int:pk>/',views.StudentDetailView.as_view(),name='student_details'),
```

(If this doesn't work, please post the code for `StudentDetailView`.)

In general, I would suggest using more descriptive URL fields, e.g. `school_pk`, `student_pk`, ... so that you can avoid making confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead
    `path("<int:pk>/",views.SchoolDetailView.as_view(),name='detail')`

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to solve this issue:

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/',SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
    
]
```

(OR):
in urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
]
```

(OR):

in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', SchoolDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
]
```